# Average salary hike in Germany for IT consultants

Tags: salary, germany, performance-reviews, consulting

I work in a small consulting firm as a Senior IT consultant in the automotive branch since the past one year. During this time, I have taken up several responsibilities in the team. I can say that I have become a very dependable resource in our team and they do not have a backup in case I am on holidays/ sick.

At the moment, there is a lot of change happening within the team and few experienced people are leaving the company and I am the one with the highest experience after they leave. This would mean that my workload due to the exits would increase tremendously.

Since my annual review is coming up soon, I am planning to ask for a 20% hike in my salary. Does anyone here know if this is a realistic hike in the German industry? What is the average hike one should expect during an annual review?

Comment: Are these people leaving on their own accord or are they getting fired? I am asking because it would be rather courageous move to ask for a huge raise when the company is currently in the process of reducing cost through downsizing.

Answer (score 3):

You can always trust the law of supply and demand.  Supply and demand work in any country, whether or not one of the parties likes it. Think about the overall IT labor market. If you have become a high demand asset, you should be able to get a good raise. Another consideration is if you are already being compensated very well or not. If you are being compensated well, then 20% would be considered a fabulous raise. Think about what they would pay a new person coming in and doing all of the tasks you think you will be doing.

You might also want to consider if they are not already going to replace some who have left and if you will really be loaded down with more tasks.